# Loop through specific column values in a data table

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Winforms app, in which I have a requirement read specific columns values specified by a condition.

here is my C# code

```
SqlCommand anc = new SqlCommand(); ;
                anc.Connection = ad;
                string s = "Sixth";
                anc.CommandText = "Select Sub_Name from Subs_Master where Semester =@Sixth ";
                anc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sixth", s);
                anc.ExecuteNonQuery();
               // SqlDataReader anw = anc.ExecuteReader();
                SqlDataAdapter al = new SqlDataAdapter(anc);
                DataSet dts = new DataSet();
                al.Fill(dts);
                DataTable dt = dts.Tables[0];
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                label9.Text = "Sixth";


foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
                {
                foreach (DataColumn Sub_Name in dt.Columns)
                {
                    //
                    //{
                    radioButton3.Text = (drow[Sub_Name.ColumnName].ToString());
                    radioButton4.Text = (drow[Sub_Name.ColumnName].ToString());
                    radioButton5.Text = (drow[Sub_Name.ColumnName].ToString());
                    radioButton6.Text = (drow[Sub_Name.ColumnName].ToString());
                    radioButton7.Text = (drow[Sub_Name.ColumnName].ToString());
                    radioButton8.Text = (drow[Sub_Name.ColumnName].ToString());
}
```

this is in referenace to a msdn walkthrough.

here is my table in
[image: data backend]

My problem is that when I run it only the last value of that column, i.e CA, is displayed on all the radio boxes, but I want each radio box to hold 6 different values, like radio3 should be Java, radio 4 should be CIMD, Radio 5 should be Network, etc.

Is there a way to do it? Or is my query wrong?

Comment: In your last "foreach" you are changing the value of each radioButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do a foreach.  By looping you are setting each radio button first to the first value, then second, then third.. until the last value.  You want to use indexing instead.

Something like this:

```
radioButton3.Text = dt.Rows[0]["SubName"] 
radioButton4.Text = dt.Rows[1]["SubName"] 
radioButton5.Text = dt.Rows[2]["SubName"]
```

As @jmcilhinney notes, your second foreach is useless.  Get rid of both of them.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are setting the `Text` of every `RadioButton` for every row.  At the end of that, each `RadioButton` will display the last value assigned, which came from the last row for every one of them.

What you need to do is just set one `RadioButton`'s `Text` property for each row and it needs to be a different `RadioButton` each time.  Either just write it out long-hand or, if you want to use a loop, put the `RadioButton`s in an array/collection and then use a `for` loop rather than a `foreach` loop.  That way, you can use the loop counter as an index into both the `RadioButton` list and the `Rows` of the `DataTable`.

By the way, get rid of that inner loop.  It serves no purpose.  You're only using data from one column so why would you loop through all the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting all radio buttons with same value. Try something like this.

```
int counter = 1;
foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
 { 
     switch (counter)
    {
        case 1:
            radioButton3.Text = drow["Sub_Name"].ToString();
            break;
        case 2:
            radioButton4.Text = drow["Sub_Name"].ToString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    counter++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the item array of each datarow via

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach(var cell in row.ItemArray)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant see how this does anything toward answering the OP's question.

Comment: He iterates the wrong way. Instead of iterate through `DataRow drow in dt.Rows` and then inside of this `DataColumn Sub_Name in dt.Columns` he should iterate through all the items in each row.

Comment: The problem is not the direction of the iteration.  This code would still set the radio buttons to the first value, then second and so on through the iteration and would wind up with all the buttons set to the 6th value at the end.

Comment: Yes sure. But that's a result of the iteration he used. The first value comes from the column iteration inside the row iteration. In his iteration he can only access the first value.

Answer (score 0):

```
radioButton3.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Sub_Name"].ToString();
radioButton4.Text = dt.Rows[1]["Sub_Name"].ToString();
radioButton5.Text = dt.Rows[2]["Sub_Name"].ToString();
radioButton6.Text = dt.Rows[3]["Sub_Name"].ToString();
radioButton7.Text = dt.Rows[4]["Sub_Name"].ToString();
radioButton8.Text = dt.Rows[5]["Sub_Name"].ToString();
```